# Can't locate gitolite_rc.pm

Tags: git, perl, gitolite

The situation is weired, we didn't do anything to the git server(a Gentoo Linux Server), and today when we try to do any operations with git, we just receive the following message:

```
Can't locate gitolite_rc.pm in @INC (you may need to install the gitolite_rc
module)     (@INC contains: /usr/bin /etc/perl /usr/local/lib64/perl5/5.18.2/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib64/perl5/5.18.2 
/usr/lib64/perl518.2/x86_64-linux /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.18.2 
/usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.18.2/x86_64-linux /usr/lib64/perl5/5.18.2 .) at 
/usr/bin/gl-auth-command line 43.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/gl-auth-command line 43.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Seems like that the gitolite_rc perl module is lost or not in the path, but we just didn't do anything to perl configs(actually we don't have any perl programmer), it just happens by itself, we are not quit familiar with perl, we've googled it, but only find the  gitolite_rc.pm file https://code.google.com/p/gitolite/source/browse/src/gitolite_rc.pm?spec=svn89e59ae7725d662919ef7dc8f759d48c173181fd&name=89e59ae772&r=89e59ae7725d662919ef7dc8f759d48c173181fd , but we just don't know what to do with it, any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Show us what's in your `PATH` and `PERL5LIB`. `ssh git@myServer \echo $PATH`. Also make sure the permissions are correct.

Comment: try to find/locate gitolite_rc.pm on the server

Answer (score 0):

[`gl-auth-command`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/g2/src/gl-auth-command) means a *really* old gitolite V2, using [`gitolite_rc.pm`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/g2/src/gitolite_rc.pm).

Its [install scripts](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/g2/src/gl-install) relies on `$GL_RC` and `$GL_BINDIR` environment variables, so check if those weren't unset somehow: the `gitweb.conf.pl` adds `GL_BINDIR` to `INC` (as I mentioned in "How to get gitolite / gitweb working together?"):

```
# now get gitolite stuff in...
unshift @INC, $ENV{GL_BINDIR};
require gitolite_rc;    gitolite_rc -> import;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much guys!

I finally found it's a problem of the perl package path. Well, we don't know why it happens, but on our server, many applications, including Nginx, Git, php-fpm... needs their own version of perl packages, with different paths. But now all the environment vars about PERL is just pointing to one particular path(a default path). So all these applications cannot find their own dependencies in that path.

Maybe I should specify the perl path for each apps, but after googled a lot, I can't find the solution, so I make it by a very lame method: just copy all the dependencies into that default perl lib path! I'm lucky that there are no conflicts and all these apps are now working properly.

Comment: Make sure at least to use the latest gitolite V3, not an old g2, as i mention in my answer.